Node - Importing .sql (and .graphql) files inside js
I am looking for a way to be able to import .sql files as string directly into my js/ts files.
Here's a simple example:
-- myFile.sql
select top 3 name from customers

// file.js
import myQuery from "myFile.sql"
console.log(myQuery) // 'select top 3 name from customers'

I'm not specifically asking for .sql files. Another possible file extension is .graphql. My question is about importing any file as a string in general.
It's easy to configure this using webpack's asset/source module, but the problem is my current project isn't using webpack!
I'm developing something with AdonisJS and seems like it uses its own bundler (but has an option to use vite).
How can I make this work? I know it's possible to read files using fs module, but I want to avoid importing an extra function just for this (readSqlAsString('./path/to/file/sql')) and dealing with promises and error handling.
So,

Is there a way to configure adonis bundler to handle importing .sql and similar files as string?
Does a custom loader for Node js exist or can I create a custom one? (Is a loader without a bundler even possible?)
I am not sure about setting up vite in my project, because it's an api server without a frontend... but, does vite support something like what webpack offers for importing assets?


I know with webpack you can use raw-loader  I wonder if adonis has somthing similar?
